# apt-get install broken and need to undo install

Tags: apt-get, debian-based, debian-stretch

Accidentally installed something, which broke during the install, which is good since I got the wrong package.

Unfortunately it's broken apt-get like others have experienced.  I've seen plenty of ways to continue the broken install, but in my case I want to **not continue** the install and just remove the offending install.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Continue the install and get the package fully installed. Then follow the instructions to uninstall it. You have given no details on what the package is or what you are doing, so that general advice is the best I can give you.

Comment: Unfortunately that would mean installing the whole GUI platform on a non-gui server, on a connection that is less than stable (talking ~4mps with constant dropouts), and just can't be bothered waiting hours for a little mistake.  Anyway just figured it out and will post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can achieve this with the command

```
$ apt-get remove --fix-broken <<PACKAGENAME>>
```

Where `<<PACKAGENAME>>` was the package that caused the breakage.  The key here was to `remove`, while all the solutions to continue with the install had `install`.

The above picked up that I was half-way through an install, and so removing it (with this flag) removed it like a charm.   If you don't have the flag, it won't identify it as being installed, which is what stumped me previously.